# CSS Text Written Out Animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, centering

I'm building a landing page for a client. Their logo is centered with the company slogan directly underneath, and currently the slogan fades in on page load.

They are now asking if the slogan can be animated to look as though it is being written out as opposed to fading in. Does anyone have an idea on how to achieve this effect? I'm stumped.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="image-wrapper">
 <a href="home.html">
  <img src="images/landing_logo2.png" />
 </a>
 <div id="test">
  <p>enter the sunshine state</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div.image-wrapper {
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
-moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
-ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
-o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.image-wrapper img {
display: block;
}

#test {
position: absolute;
top: 100%;
width: 100%;
}

#test p {
width: 100%;
font-family: segoe;
font-size: 18px;
text-align: center;
color: #fff;
margin-top: -40px;
-webkit-animation: fadein 8s; /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
   -moz-animation: fadein 8s; /* Firefox < 16 */
    -ms-animation: fadein 8s; /* Internet Explorer */
     -o-animation: fadein 8s; /* Opera < 12.1 */
        animation: fadein 8s;
}

@keyframes fadein {
from { opacity: 0; }
to   { opacity: 1; }
}
```

I've attached a JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/1r3fuk27/

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29911143/how-can-i-animate-the-drawing-of-text-on-a-web-page/29911203#29911203

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using external libraries, you can simply do it with this approach.

```js
var slogan = "enter the sunshine state";
for (var i = 0; i < slogan.length; i++) {
  (function(i) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#test > p').text(slogan.substring(0, i + 1));
    }, 100 * i);
  }(i));
}
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: segoe;
  src: url(fonts/segoesc.ttf);
}
div.image-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.image-wrapper img {
  display: block;
}
#test {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
#test p {
  width: 100%;
  font-family: segoe;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000;
  margin-top: -40px;
  -webkit-animation: fadein 8s;
  /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
  -moz-animation: fadein 8s;
  /* Firefox < 16 */
  -ms-animation: fadein 8s;
  /* Internet Explorer */
  -o-animation: fadein 8s;
  /* Opera < 12.1 */
  animation: fadein 8s;
}
@keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
/* Firefox < 16 */

@-moz-keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
/* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */

@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
/* Internet Explorer */

@-ms-keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
/* Opera < 12.1 */

@-o-keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="image-wrapper">
  <a href="home.html">
    <img src="http://japesfawcett.com/testsh/images/landing_logo2.png" />
  </a>

  <div id="test">
    <p>enter the sunshine state</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

If the text is not visible in the snippet [**here**](https://jsfiddle.net/arunatebel/voah4ey0/2/) is the fiddle

Comment: lol yeah, I forgot to remove the code I used to debug... If it worked, you can accept it as the answer ;)

Comment: Thanks, this is a good solution - my only issue is with changing the font and text color, do you know how I could do that?

Comment: Oops @shaz sorry I actually mistook you as the OP! :D

Comment: @dash167 : Glad to help and to know that you figured it out ;)

Answer (score 0):

you can do so using pure JavaScript as follows -

```
function type() {
    var el = document.getElementById('test').querySelector(' p');
    var slogan = el.innerHTML;
    el.innerHTML = '';
    var i = 0;
    setInterval(function() {
        var char = slogan.substr(i, 1);
        el.innerHTML += char;
        i++;
    }, 250); // change 250 as per typing speed you need
}
type(); // call the function whenever you need
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qjm4ajm4/)